# Can't seem to clear the s.events when I have a s.tl() call. how can I clear s.events out?

Tags: javascript, adobe-analytics

Omniture Tracking Question:

I have a module on my page that loads some third party information. When that module loads I call a "s.tl()" call. Unfortunetly, if I have clicked previuosly on a link or somesuch in the site then the s.events has a value in it.

So, when the module loads... that 's.events' value gets sticky and then is passed when I call s.tl() when the module is loaded. Thus, dbl counted clicks and such. I NEED for that s.events to be empty when that module loads and I call the s.tl(). how?

I tried just normal js assignments. ala s.events = "", I tried clearVars() plugin method, no go.. nothing seems to work.

Any help?

Comment: One question to make things more clear. Do you clean the s.events directly after a request or before the module request? Could you send a small fragment of implemented code?

Comment: To solve this issue elegantly, override s.t(). See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28048759/when-and-how-to-use-s-clearvars-in-omniture/46960014#46960014

Answer (score 0):

You can try `s.events.length = 0;` to reset it back to empty.

Answer (score 0):

Normally clearing the variables out is not necessary, as you define the proper variables you wish to track before submitting a link tracking image request. All variables are reset after each page load.

If you want to clear the events variable out, you can simply use:

```
s.events=null;
```

Either that or define the events variable with different events prior to calling your next image request.

Comment: The `s.tl()` function is often used without re-loading the page. So often the `s.events` string may not be empty.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might need to wrap your s.tl() call in a function. Here's an example of how I've implemented my s.tl() calls.  Hopefully this helps you. :)

```
function trackOmniEvent(eventString, eventLabel) {
    /* uses global namespace s */
    // set vars
    s.linkTrackVars="eVar58,events";
    s.linkTrackEvent="event20";
    s.events="event20";
    s.eVar58=eventString;
    // run tracker
    s.tl(this,'o',eventLabel);
    // reset vars
    s.linkTrackVars="None";
    s.linkTrackEvent="None";
    s.eVar58="";
    s.events="";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always set `s.linkTrackEvents` and `s.linkTrackVars` whenever you make an `s.tl()` call.
So in your case you will be doing something like this:

```
s.linkTrackVars = "prop25,eVar25";
s.linkTrackEvents = "none";
s.prop25 = 'someValue';
s.eVar25 = 'someValue';
s.tl(true, 'o', 'linkName');
```

This will reset any predefined events when making `s.tl()` calls.

Example when you have an event:

```
s.linkTrackVars = "prop25,eVar25,events";
s.linkTrackEvents = "event25";
s.prop25 = 'someValue';
s.eVar25 = 'someValue';
s.event25 = 'someEventValue';
s.tl(true, 'o', 'linkName');
```