# Adobe DTM: Multiple Event rule in a page having issue

Tags: adobe, adobe-analytics

I have created 3 different event based rule in a page to track 3 different buttons in a page. When I click on the first link it is fine. But when the second link is clicked it fires 2 times with the value I set for the 1st button and the current button.

When I click the third button it fires again 2 times with the previous click event and the present one. Can you please let me know how to stop this?

This the code that I have.

```
<div class="container1 wireBlock" id="hero" style="top: 0px;">
  <div id="lensFlare" style="top: 150px;"></div>
  <section class="banner">
            <h1>THIS</h1>
            <h2>xxx</h2>
            <a class="js-loadVideo" href="#">
              <img border="0" alt="logo" src="/us/media/play-button.png" width="100" height="100">Play Video</a>
  </section>
</div>
```

The selector used is #hero a.js-loadVideo

The other button that I have on the same page is

```
<a class="button blue" href="www.test.com" target="_blank">Register Now</a>
```

If I click on Register Now it is firing the value that I have set for the top button.

Comment: Can you post any code you're using in the rules? Also post what selectors you're using, and post the HTML code for the buttons themselves (or just link to the page in question and I can take a look.)

It sounds like some of your selectors may be overlapping, or the rules are based on similar variables whose state affects the other rules.

Comment: After checking all the custom tracking in our site my understanding is custom link tracking works perfect when you click for the 1st time. After clicking on the links for multiple times it caches the value and fires the same value. The problem that i am facing is  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9204429/cant-seem-to-clear-the-s-events-when-i-have-a-s-tl-call-how-can-i-clear-s-ev for which i don't see the correct answer. Any idea how to fix this? Iam sure many people are using multiple custom tracking in a single page. In this case how are you avoiding this issue?

Comment: Try clearing all the evars, events and props after your click event for each button.

Comment: If you need to do custom link tracking a different way, instead of setting a value in the "Custom Link Name" field in DTM, try directly setting s.pev2 to that value. That'll overwrite any previous value. And definitely make sure you're overwriting your s.events and s.linkTrackVars before you call s.tl() or in the analytics code of a DTM rule.

Comment: Please do not mark any of your questions as urgent. Volunteers will respond to you at their leisure - if you need speedy assistance, a freelancer is a more suitable option.

Comment: I tried using the function to clear evar and evets.var s = _satellite.getToolsByType('sc')[0].getS();
s.clearVars();
return true; It gives the error saying s.clearVars() is not a function.

Comment: Iam not using AppMeasurement yet so I will not be able to use s.clearVars(). For the old s_code.js what should be the function that i should be using to clear evars and events.

Comment: @vids reset the values of eVar manually from UI

Comment: you mean to say i set the value of evar == null from UI and then again assign from the custom js?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like something I have had trouble with this in the past. I used the following to get this to fix:

1. Search your s_code for the following plugin/utility by searching for "clearVars":

   ```
   /* Utility manageVars v1.4 - clear variable values (requires split 1.5)*/
   /* */
   /* editing out code not relevant to question */
       s.clearVars=new Function("t","var s=this;s[t]='';");
   /* editing out code not relevant to question */
   ```
2. In the Criteria section of all your event-based rules select "Custom" and add the following code:

   ```
   s.manageVars("clearVars","events,",1)
   return true;
   ```

If you are missing the s_code piece you can get it by downloading a more recent s_code file from Adobe